# Backface Culling Toggle Button for Blender GUI project

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I have been working on my project for Blender for quite some time and have reached the end of this small section, but I want to add a toggle button to the GUI that toggles if backface culling is off or not, I have tried using the command:

```
bpy.context.space_data.shading.show_backface_culling = True
```

and the opposite but when I run it in the python script, it says:

> "SpaceTextEditor" object has no attribute shading

I know it's probably something really simple.

Comment: Don't know whether this helps as I don't know python in Blender:  If you hover over the checkbox with Python tooltips enabled in Preferences > Interface > Display, the tooltip shows "bpy.data.materials["Material"].use_backface_culling".

Answer (score 1):

When you run [`bpy.context.space_data`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.space_data) in the [`TextEditor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html), the context will be within *Text Editor* by default, and thus `space_data` will be of type [`SpaceTextEditor`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceTextEditor.html). When you run that code line in the [`Python Console`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html), the context will be within the *Python Console* by default, and thus `space_data` will be of type [`SpaceConsole`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceConsole.html). But the attribute [`shading`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.shading) is part of the [`SpaceView3D`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html) class so you have to [override the context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add) to be within the [`3D Viewport`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/index.html) which you can do by using the following script:

```
import bpy

area_type = 'VIEW_3D'
areas  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == area_type]

if len(areas) <= 0:
    raise Exception(f"Make sure an Area of type {area_type} is open or visible in your screen!")

with bpy.context.temp_override(area=areas[0]):
    bpy.context.space_data.shading.show_backface_culling = False
```

Comment: I like that you went ahead and added a check for the area's existence.

Comment: thanks! yeah new users may get confused when they run a script and it didn't work, just because the area was not there in their workspace. Also easy to debug a problem :)